# Getting this from javascript event listener in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So for touch devices I have a couple of event listeners for `touchstart` and `touchmove`. Everything else has events bound by jQuery, but for some reason this didn't work for the touch events so they are bound using javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchstart);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchmove);
```

The problem with this is that when I want to trigger an event from a jQuery bound event, I can just use, for example:

```
this.scrollContainer();
```

However, the context of `this` is different within the javascript bound event which means that I cannot trigger the event this way.

My question is, is it possible to trigger this event from the javascript bound event? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [_.bind()](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to pass a custom context to the callback

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', _.bind(this.touchstart, this));
document.addEventListener('touchmove', _.bind(this.touchmove, this));
```